# error when concatenating printer name with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, concatenation, zebra-printers

It is about looking for the printers that the system has installed, but when finding them the JavaScript code concatenates a% 20 in the blank space between the "brand" (Zebra) and the "model" (GC420t) ... I attach an image

[image: screenshot]

the problem is that when I pass this parameter to the function PrintCommands does not recognize the printer ... the truth .... in the combo it shows me the name of the printer correctly ..

[image: Combobox printers]

My View:

```
<h3>Impresión de Etiquetas</h3>

<div>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="useDefaultPrinter" /> <strong>Usar impresora por defecto</strong> o...
    </label>
</div>

<div id="loadPrinters">
    Click para buscar impresoras instaladas...
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:jsWebClientPrint.getPrinters();" value="Load installed printers..." />
    <br /><br />
</div>

<div id="installedPrinters" style="visibility:hidden">
    <label for="installedPrinterName">Select an installed Printer:</label>
    <select name="installedPrinterName" id="installedPrinterName"></select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var wcppGetPrintersTimeout_ms = 10000; //10 sec
    var wcppGetPrintersTimeoutStep_ms = 500; //0.5 sec

    function wcpGetPrintersOnSuccess() {
        // Display client installed printers
        if (arguments[0].length > 0) {
            var p = arguments[0].split("|");
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                options += '<option>' + p[i] + '</option>';
            }
            $('#installedPrinters').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#installedPrinterName').html(options);
            $('#installedPrinterName').focus();
            $('#loadPrinters').hide();
        } else {
            alert("No printers are installed in your system.");
        }
    }
    function wcpGetPrintersOnFailure() {
        // Do something if printers cannot be got from the client
        alert("No printers are installed in your system.");
    }
</script>

<br />

<input type="button" style="font-size:18px" onclick="javascript:jsWebClientPrint.print('useDefaultPrinter=' + $('#useDefaultPrinter').attr('checked') + '&printerName=' + $('#installedPrinterName').val());" value="Print ZPL..." />


@section scripts{

    @* Register the WebClientPrint script code generated by PrintZPLController. *@

    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.WCPScript);

}
```

I do not understand how that "% 20" can get to concatenate with the space between brand and model .... any help for me?

pd: when passing the name without "% 20" as parameter, the script works correctly

Comment: A hint: %20 is the space character when encoded for a URL. From what you've shown, there is no space between % and 20, despite what you've written. Sounds like this `getPrinters` function is encoding the names.

Comment: BTW, there is no reason to put `javascript:` in your `onclick` attributes; that's only needed if the element is an anchor (`a`) and you're putting the JavaScript in its `href`.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, will I correct it, any additional suggestions for me? @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: I have no idea what the `jsWebClientPrint` is, so no more suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of URL-decode function in your back end code. I don't know C# very well, but I think you'd do something like this:

```
printerName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(printerName);
```

...at the start of PrintCommands().